# Array[] - Can't get the value in Array[] C# "cannot implicitly convert type object to int"

Tags: c#, arrays, object

example :

```
Array[] hasil = new Array[1];
hasil[0] = new int[1];
hasil[0].SetValue(99, 0);
int xx = hasil[0].GetValue(0);
```

why I can't get `hasil[0].GetValue(0)` it say "cannot implicitly convert type object to int"

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're using an `Array[]` filled with `int[]` instead of using directly an `int[][]`?

Comment: because sometimes the data not always `int[]` and n params

Answer (score 2):

`GetValue` method returns `object` type so you have to explicitly convert it to `int`

Like this

```
int xx = (int)hasil[0].GetValue(0);
```

Comment: Extra info: In the Array class you can find: 'public object GetValue(int index);' So as [Pawan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/804517/pawan-nogariya) noted, the return type of the GetValue method is object.

Comment: Welcome! If it works for you, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your value:

```
(int)hasil[0].GetValue(0);
```

When your compilator says it can't implicitly cast, you have to do it explicitly. Then add a cast.